# Why is my view not rendering?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm learning BackboneJS using a book called beginning backbone, 
as far as I understood I can render my own el elements.
however when I call the render function it doesn't render anything on the page, 
when I use console.log(view.el); it outputs what should be rendered so I guess its an issue with the render function.

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:
    {
        title: "default title",
        author: "default author",
        pages: 0
    }
}); 

var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book
});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function()
    {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function()
    {
        this.$el.html('Hello Library');
        return this;            
    }
});

var book1 = new Book({title: "title1",author:"author1",pages: 11});
var book2 = new Book({title: "title2",author:"author2",pages: 2});

var library = new Library([book1,book2]);

var view = new View({
    model: book1,
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'page',
    attributes: {'data-date': new Date()}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/nWvRy/

The problem you had is that you specified tagName and className, which will render a detached node.  You must then manually attach that node onto some place on the screen for it to appear.  The other option (which I have done) is to specify an `el` attribute for an element already on the screen, then the view will be rendered (attached) to that pre-existing node.  You can use `el` **or** `tagName`, `className` and `attributes` but not both.

HTML:

```
<div id="view-wrapper"></div>
```

JS:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:
    {
        title: "default title",
        author: "default author",
        pages: 0
    }
}); 

var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book
});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function()
    {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function()
    {
        this.$el.html('Hello Library');
        return this;            
    }
});

var book1 = new Book({title: "title1",author:"author1",pages: 11});
var book2 = new Book({title: "title2",author:"author2",pages: 2});

var library = new Library([book1,book2]);

var view = new View({
    model: book1,
    el: '#view-wrapper',
    attributes: {'data-date': new Date()}
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's another version which uses `tagName`, `className` and `attributes`.  Notice how the view render() method has to attach it to an existing element.

http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/nWvRy/1/

Comment: I wish I could like this more than once